# Loading a Collection View Cell from storyboard (instead of from nib with registerNib)

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, xcode5, uistoryboard

In Xcode 5.0.2 I'm trying to recreate Michael Lehman's "Collection View" example for his video tutorial [Learning To Build Apps For iPhone And iPad](http://techbus.safaribooksonline.com/video/programming/mobile/9781771370813) (password protected on Safari; the chapter 5).

Michael loads a Collection View Cell from a nib file with the following code (here the full version of his [ExploreUICollectionView/ViewController.m](http://pastebin.com/szc5kGaZ)):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.myCollectionView.delegate = self;
    self.myCollectionView.dataSource = self;

    self.cellData = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    for(int i=0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        [self.cellData addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"#%d", i+1]];
    }

    UINib *cellNib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"CVCell"
                                    bundle:nil];
    [self.myCollectionView registerNib:cellNib
            forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CVCell"];
}
```

I however would like not to create a separate nib file for the cell, but drag a View to the `Main_iphone.stroryboard` and `Main_ipad.storyboard`, give it a "Storyboard ID" if needed and then (somehow) use it in `myCollectionView`.

**My question is** which methods should I call then please?

I can not use a `nibWithNibName` and `registerNib:forCellWithReuseIdentifier` here.

**UPDATE:** rdelmar's advice [has worked](https://github.com/afarber/ios-newbie/tree/master/MyCollection) (thanks!):

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can't drag a view into a storyboard, only view controllers. To do it in a storyboard, you add a collection view to a controller, or drag out a collection view controller. You will get a single cell in that collection view, to which you can add any subviews you want. Give the cell a reuse identifier, and don't register anything in your controller code. You can make a subclass of UICollectionViewCell if you want, and change the class of that cell to your subclass.

Comment: This has worked well, thank you. Do you happend to have an advice on how to configure the gaps between the cells? I can't figure the setting in storyboard (please see the new screenshot)

Comment: Collection view will put as many cells across the screen as will fit (if you're using the standard flow layout), so how big the gaps are depends on how big the cells are, how much of an inset that you give them in collectionView:layout:insetForSectionAtIndex:, and the minimum spacing between items (collectionView:layout:minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex:). Look at the UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout protocol for specifics on these methods.

Comment: +1 for 'don't register anything in your controller code'. V. important.

Comment: Thanks, This helped me. Common mistake we do is register it in controller code as well as in storyboard with identifier eventually leading to controller class being overriden during runtime.